# How to check if last record has been reached

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code which returns a possible 4 rows from tblItems. If however, any row being selected happens to be the last row in tblItems, How do I return @lastBox as "Y"

I set up DECLARE @lastBox   varchar(1) which I want to return a Y or N to say if it's the last box or not. Not sure where to go from there.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectBoxes]
@bootSaleDate   DATE,
@itemcategory   Int,
@page  Int

AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   select * from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateAdded desc) as [RowNo],  bootSaleDate,  '<a href="https://www.myUrl.co.uk/video.aspx?oid='  + CAST(ISNULL([fileID],'') AS NVARCHAR(5)) + '"><br /><image width="140" height="200" src="catalog/thumbnails/' + convertedFilename + '" /></a>' as strText, fileID, [buyPrice] as buyPrice

   FROM [tblItems] WHERE sold='n' AND itemCategory=@itemCategory)t

   where RowNo between (@page*4)-3 AND (@page*4)

   DECLARE @lastBox   varchar(1)

END
```

Comment: `(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateAdded desc)` to warn you this can still result into a non deterministic (random) results as i assume `dateAdded ` does not have a primary or unique key? To get pure deterministic (fixed) results always you should also include a column in the `ORDER BY` which has a primary or unique key assuming the id column has you should be using `ORDER BY dateAdded  DESC, id DESC` to get pure deterministic (fixed) results always.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the row number to the count:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN RowNo < cnt THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS box
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateAdded desc) as [RowNo],
        COUNT(*) OVER () cnt,
        bootSaleDate,  '<a href="https://www.myUrl.co.uk/video.aspx?oid='  + CAST(ISNULL([fileID],'') AS NVARCHAR(5)) + '"><br /><image width="140" height="200" src="catalog/thumbnails/' + convertedFilename + '" /></a>' as strText, fileID, [buyPrice] as buyPrice
    FROM [tblItems]
    WHERE sold = 'n' AND itemCategory = @itemCategory
) t
WHERE RowNo BETWEEN (@page*4)-3 AND (@page*4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. How do I then return this Y or N value ?

Comment: I am not so well versed with stored procedure syntax.  The alias `box` in my query will tell you whether a row is the last one in a result set or not.

Comment: @markdavies Tim included the flag as a column in the resultset. If you want that flag to be available without traversing the resultset, you could generate a second resultset or use an output parameter.

Comment: Not completely sure how to do that. I'm still learning.. apologies. I just tried IF box='Y' then set @lastbox='Y' . Then I was going to select @lastBox but it says box isn't a column.